# A logic problem: $[\lnot q \to (r \lor w), (\lnot q \land p), (p \to \lnot w)] \to r$

Tags: logic

Will somebody please solve this completely for me?
$$[\lnot q \to (r \lor w), (\lnot q \land p), (p \to \lnot w)] \to r$$

I did it but got stuck at the end

Here is my incomplete answer
[image]

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this.  You have $\neg q$, so you have $r \vee w$; you have $p$, so you have $\neg w$; you have $r \vee w$, so you have $\neg w \to r$; so at last you have $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Based on what you had done in the attempt, I believe you want to prove this use logical equivalence, the ',' should means 'and'.

Until you write the following, everything else is correct

> [image]

This is just the wrong way to apply the de morgan's law, apply it correcly we should get
$$\boxed{[(\neg q\land\neg r\land\neg w)\lor (q\lor \neg p)\lor(p\land w)]\lor r}$$
Try again see if you can prove this is a tautology.

**Answer**

\begin{align}
&[(¬q→(r∨w))\land(¬q∧p)\land(p→¬w)]\to r\\
\equiv&[(q\lor r\lor w)\land(¬q\land p)\land(\neg p\lor \neg w)]\to r\\
\equiv&\boxed{(\neg q\land \neg r\land \neg w)\lor q\lor \neg p\lor(p\land w)\lor r}\\
\equiv&(\neg q\land \neg r\land \neg w)\lor q\lor ((\neg p\lor p)\land(\neg p\lor w))\lor r\\
\equiv&(\neg q\land \neg r\land \neg w)\lor q\lor (\top\land(\neg p\lor w))\lor r\\
\equiv&(\neg q\land \neg r\land \neg w)\lor q\lor \neg p\lor w\lor r\\
\equiv&((\neg q\lor q)\land (\neg r\lor q)\land (\neg w\lor q))\lor \neg p\lor w\lor r\\
\equiv&(\top\land (\neg r\lor q)\land (\neg w\lor q))\lor \neg p\lor w\lor r\\
\equiv&((\neg r\lor q)\land(\neg w\lor q))\lor \neg p\lor w\lor r\\
\equiv&((\neg r\lor q\lor w)\land(\neg w\lor q\lor w))\lor \neg p\lor r\\
\equiv&((\neg r\lor q\lor w)\land\top)\lor \neg p\lor r\\
\equiv&\neg r\lor q\lor w\lor \neg p\lor r\\
\equiv&q\lor w\lor \neg p\lor \top\\
\equiv&\top
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather easy:

1. $\lnot q \land p$ (hypothesis 2).
2. $\lnot q$ (from 1)
3. $\lnot q \to (r \lor w)$ (hypothesis 1).
4. $r \lor w$ (modus ponens, from 2 and 3).
5. $p$ (from 1)
6. $p \to \lnot w$ (hypothesis 3)
7. $\lnot w$ (modus ponens from 5,6)

and then deduce $r$ from $4$ and $7$. (Which requires the law of the excluded middle; systems will vary in how to deduce it).